# How do we co-ordinate many teams work on the same Jira ticket?

Tags: jira, application-software-testing

#### How do we have many teams (Security, Functional, performance) work on same JIRA (bug or enhancement) and put their results?

I use JIRA for defect management, SDLC and release management.
There are JIRA tickets which need testing from all 3 teams (Performance, Security, Functional), How do we make a workflow, where each team post their testing results and then only JIRA moves to next phase.

Answer (score 1):

Jira provides multiple levels, i.e.

- Epic
- Story
- Task
- Subtask

Your task will be to study them and, relevant to your particular situation (enough details not provided) you will need to decide which to utilize at which levels.  From your description I would expect that Story with tasks is probably the right level.  Depending on more details it might be Epic with stories (unlikely though) or Task with subtasks. As usual 'it all depends'.

Answer (score 1):

The most feasible strategy followed by the quality assurance services to manage the inputs from different teams in the same JIRA ticket is to break down the parent ticket into sub-tickets, followed by assigning each sub-ticket to the responsible team. Each team can add details like goal, technical detail, and expected outcomes to their respective tickets.

JIRA provides us the ability to create different types of tickets like *Epics, Stories, Task, and Sub-tasks* for managing the tasks. This can be used as per the requirement.

***To Exemplify:***
Let say, we have to an parent feature: the Login and Sign up modules.
Based upon the efforts required from different teams, we can opt to create either create Story or tasks.
Further, depending upon the requirement each team create sub-tasks in their tickets.

- **Epic:** Login & Sign Up Feature

  **Tasks under that Epic:**

  - **Task1:** [Product] Design Login & Signup pages
  - **Task2:** [Dev] Login and Sign-up feature modules development
  - **Task3:** [Functional] Login & Signup feature validation

    - **SubTask1:** [Web] Login & Signup feature validation on Web
    - **SubTask2:** [Mobile] Login & Signup feature validation on Mobile
  - **Task4:** [Security] Login & Signup feature security test and results
  - **Task5:** [Performance] Login & Signup feature performance tests and results